# How do I position a right-floating div block at the top of its parent element, when I have other existing div blocks that float to the left?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am having trouble with blocks of HTML that need to float right, but also be at the very top of the parent div. Currently, they do float to the right, but they are positioned UNDER the existing div blocks I have that are floating to the left.

I need to have the right-floating divs to be at the TOP of their parent div block.

How do I get them there?

You may need to view example in Full Page mode to see the issue.

```html
<div id="sel_main">
  <style type="text/css">
    /* outer fieldset container */
    
    #slp_selection_request_form fieldset {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    
    #slp_debug_fieldset label {
      display: block;
    }
    
    #slp_debug_fieldset label span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 75px
    }
  </style>

  <div style="background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 3px; border: 1px solid #000000;">

    <div class="box" id="input">

      <div id="input_data">

        <form action="#" method="POST" name="slp_selection_request_form" id="slp_selection_request_form">

          <fieldset id="slp_debug_fieldset">
            <legend class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Results</legend>
            <fieldset>
              <legend class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Sort By</legend>
              <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="slp_debug_fieldset[sort_by]" value="efficiency" checked="checked">Efficiency</label>
              <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="slp_debug_fieldset[sort_by]" value="price">Price</label>
            </fieldset>
          </fieldset>
          <fieldset id="submit">
            <legend class="ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">Show Selections</legend>
            <input type="submit" name="submit[submit]" id="submit_button" value="Submit">
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div id="warnings" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 45px; width: 550px; clear: both; ">
      Warnings
    </div>

    <div style="clear:both"></div>
    <div style="vertical-align: middle; float: right; padding-left: 15px; font: normal normal 600 24pt arial;margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;">Must be at the Top</div>

    <div style="float: right; color: red; font-weight: bold; font-size:1.4em;margin-left:auto; margin-right:0;">
      <p>This block 1 needs to float right and be at the top</p>
      <p>This block 2 needs to float right and be at the top</p>
    </div>

    <div class="box" id="output" style="display: none; clear: both; margin-top: 10px;"></div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: my guess is that left-floating divs are covering the entire available width of the page.  But I need to curtail them so that they don't.  How, I don't yet know, because I don't want to them to have a fixed width

Comment: Reorder your `html` so that the two `divs` with the text stating they must sit at the top right of the page, are situated before the `top left float divs` in the html.

Answer (score 0):

I moved "Must be at the Top" div to be before `id="input"`, and floated it right.

Then I moved `block 1` div under "Must be at the Top" div, and set `position: absolute;right:40px;` and I now live happily ever after.